# Setting a Perl variable as an environment variable

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I'm trying to set a variable I previously set in a Perl script as an environment variable, but it seems to not realize the parameter I'm passing in is a variable and not the actual path I want.

For example, when I run this:

```
$ENV{'ENV_VARIABLE'}='\'$file_path\'';
print($ENV{'ENV_VARIABLE'});
```

I only get:

```
'$file_path'
```

Is there any way I can tell it that what I'm passing in is actually a variable and not a literal string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Perl, single quoted strings do not interpolate variables.  You want to use a double quote:

```
$ENV{'ENV_VARIABLE'}= "'$file_path'";
```

In that line, the rvalue is interpreted as `q{'} . $file_path . q{'}` where `q{'}` is a fancy way of writing `'\''`, which is a bit harder to read.